# How to encrypt and lock selected folders

Tags: encryption, directory

Now that cryptkeeper is dead and buried is there a reliable alternative or a built-in tool in Ubuntu to encrypt and lock selected folders?

Comment: Have you tried `encfs`?

Comment: @George, encfs may not be a good option considering the security warning which reads: "... the current implementation of Encfs is vulnerable or potentially vulnerable to multiple types of attacks. ... Until these issues are resolved, encfs should not be considered a safe home for sensitive data in scenarios where such attacks are possible." As cryptkeeper was a just a GUI frontend for encfs, perhaps, this is why it's now dead.

Answer (score 0):

SiriKali[1] is a viable alternative and its in ubuntu repositories[2]

[1] https://mhogomchungu.github.io/sirikali/

[2] https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sirikali

ps:
SiriKali is my project.